# Chromium in raspbian is not loading fonts

Tags: raspbian, fonts, unicode, chrome

I have flash project which has verdana/lohit font embedded into it  but they do not load and shows boxes in Chromium (Chromium 65.0.3325.181) in raspbian. However same project gets loaded when ran in chromium (Chromimum 66.0.3359.181) in Ubuntu 18. I have install all truetype fonts from ubuntu machine to raspberry pi but still not working.

**In raspbian:**
[image]

**In Ubuntu 18.04:**
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this was ever answered or figured out but I had the same kind of issue and I ended up installing all of the google font's which resolved my issue.

```
sudo curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/qrpike/Web-Font-Load/master/install.sh | bash
```

Posting encase someone else run's into this.